# Length of Computer Modern TFM files

Tags: fonts, tex-core, ctan, tex-history

With the exception of `cmfi10.tfm` and `cmmi5.tfm`, all the TFM files in the [Computer Modern distribution](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/tfm) have an extra 0x00 byte at the end, which makes them one byte longer than claimed by their first two bytes (their `lf` integer). Incidentally(?), the two exceptions are newer files (they date from 1996-07-08 rather than 1992-08-10).

Why is this? Were the newer files generated by a different version of Metafont? The TFM specification in the `tex.web` and `mf.web` source code does not mention the extra 0x00.

When I compiled a version of TeX with ISO Pascal, I had to omit some end-of-file checks from the original WEB program, because they worked only if the extra 0x00 byte was present. Therefore my change file contains the following

```pascal
@x
if eof(tfm_file) then abort;
for k:=np+1 to 7 do font_info[param_base[f]+k-1].sc:=0;
@y
{|eof(tfm_file)| is true after the last byte has been read}
for k:=np+1 to 7 do font_info[param_base[f]+k-1].sc:=0;
@z
```

Has any version of TeX had a problem with the extra 0x00 or its absence? I assume that every version has system-dependent changes in the file system interface anyway.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: If I do `hexdump` on `cmr10.tfm`, I don't see a `00` final byte. How are you looking at the file?

Comment: I wrote a Node.js program to fetch the files from the CTAN archive and looked at the byte stream in the response. I learned from the [tex-k mailing list](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-k/2018-February/002849.html) that the TeX Live distribution doesn't have the extra 0x00.

Comment: Serious question: Why and in what context does that matter?

Comment: It matters for the end-of-file checks in the TeX program. Without my change file, ISO Pascal detected `eof(fmt_file)` and reported "bad format" when reading the `cmfi10.tfm` file. I would like to know whether to adapt the TFM file or the reading routine.

Comment: To answer your last question: as far as I can see, you should adapt the tfm file. Those extra null bytes are wrong, as we discussed when you wrote to tex-k. I am discussing with CTAN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TFM files have been updated in the [CTAN archive](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/tfm) and now have the length that is claimed by their `lf` integer. In other words: A superfluous final 0x00 has been removed. Thanks to all involved!

For my ISO Pascal change file this means that statements like

```
if eof(tfm_file) then abort;
```

must continue to be commented out, because of the way I read files with ISO Pascal.